How to create this specific timeline in Flutter?

I want to create this kind of timeline widget in Flutter where I am getting the list of thresholds from the back-end, so that can be dynamic like [50,100,250,300]. I have one achieved value, such as 175. I want to create the widgets exactly like this where achieved and unachieved nodes and dividers have separate colors.
The code I have tried is shown below
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const differance = 300; //two points differance
    const certainPoint = 600;
    const firstThresold = 400;
    const secondThresold = 700;
    const width = 150;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Text("350"),
                Container(
                  height: 10,
                  width: 10,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: ((certainPoint - firstThresold) / differance) * width,
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 5,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: ((secondThresold - certainPoint) / differance) * width,
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 5,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 10,
              width: 10,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
     );
    }

Now I want it to be exactly like the above mentioned picture with the dynamic value. Can anyone help me with it ? This is beyond my coding knowledge currently.

so instead of const Text("350") you have to pass to a Text widget a string coming from your backend - it has to be done in Row.children property so that it forms your timeline

I guess u don't  get my point @pskink . I want to acieve the above design values I can assign also

Is 350 taken from a backend or it's a hardcoded value?

That can be come from backend @pskink

so you have to pass your backend data to a Text widget instead of hardcoded 350 as it is now

@pskink Yeah. so can you help me replicating the same design which I have mentioned

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Try below code with Row and Column. Hope it helps...
     Row(
        crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "350",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 10,
                width: 10,
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero, // Removes any default margin
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 2),
            ],
          ),
          // Adjust the space between the dot and line
          const SizedBox(
            width: ((certainPoint - firstThresold) / differance) *
                width, // Space between the first divider
            child: Divider(
              thickness: 5,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: ((secondThresold - certainPoint) / differance) *
                width, // Space between the second divider
            child: Divider(
              thickness: 5,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "350",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 10,
                width: 10,
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero, // Removes any default margin
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 2),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )


this design is not accurate as I need to create a whole section of timelines as per my list. Can you check what I am trying to achieve and give me solution on that @DroidFlutter
